# расширение модели user

Tags: python, django

в стандартной модели user всего лишь имя и пароль, но мне нужно, чтобы при регистрации можно было еще указать email, дату рождения и еще пару полей. Как мне это сделать? И да, я знаю о способах расширения модели, но я не могу найти нормальный пример, как это сделать

Comment: В первую очередь вам необходимо изучить [официальную документация по данному вопросу](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model), где очень подробно с примерами все описано. Если что-то не получится, тогда выклыдывайте свой код и что именно не получается. А пока вопрос не тянет на статус "хорошего вопроса".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю создать отдельную модель `Profile` и связать её с `User`.

***models.py:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    birthday = models.DateField()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_or_create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        try:
            instance.profile.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Профиль можно редактировать так:

```py
user.profile.email = "nomnoms12@example.com"
user.save()
```